# Build apache with fastcgi (as static linked module)

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi

I've downloaded [apache source](http://off.co.il/apache//httpd/httpd-2.2.17.tar.gz) and [FastCGI source](http://www.fastcgi.com/dist/fcgi.tar.gz).
Now, I wish to add FastCGI as a static module to apache (NOT DSO).
[I've read the installation guide](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/mod_fcgid/trunk/README-FCGID) @ svn.apache.org, but still couldn't make it work. I can't find the fastcgi module after installing it by those instructions. Any idea would be appreciated.